# C++ Macro to replace text with nothing

Tags: c++, macros

Macros are often used for text substitution. In my case, I need to conditionally wipe out some keywords, so that compilation will be possible in compilers that don't have the specific feature.

Specifically I've been looking into [cpp11 range](https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range) where this snippet comes from

```
template <typename C>
struct has_size {
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*) -> // problem in VS2013
        typename std::is_integral<
            decltype(std::declval<T const>().size())>::type;
// .. some more stuff
};
```

I'm providing this as the example that spawned the question. In the above code I ended up doing

```
template <typename T>
static 
#if COMPILE_WITH_GCC_NEW_ENOUGH
    constexpr 
#endif
auto check(T*) ->
```

because there were other parts where `constexpr` needed to be replaced with `const` in order to compile.

What I'm asking is a way to say eg

```
#define Constexpr ?????????
```

so that it would be replaced by `constexpr` in gcc compilations and **textually nothing** in VS compilations.

Comment: Simply `#define constexpr`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly, simply:

```
#define constexpr
```

will expand `constexpr` to nothing. You can wrap this macro definition inside an appropriate `#if` for your compiler that doesn't support this.

Sometimes people make the "empty" expansion more explicit:

```
#define constexpr /* nothing */
```

Comment: I have seen this so many times in include guards that I somehow deduced it only _defines_ a symbol for checking with `#ifndef` or `#ifdef`. Thanks for the quick response