# "#define" vs "#define 1"

Tags: c++, c, include, c-preprocessor

The `1` seems unnecessary (and possibly misleading) in the following example, but I have seen this multiple times when used for checking `#ifdef`s:

```
#ifndef __NEWLIB_H__

#define __NEWLIB_H__ 1
```

Is there a difference or reason for using the above versus a plain `#define __NEWLIB_H__`?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__NEWLIB_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, this code is actually from (or "is") the implementation.

Comment: @abc To be clear, by "implementation", Pete means the implementation of the C++ langauge. Not implementation of your functions (unless you are writing the standard library).

Comment: @eerorika Newlib is an implementation of the standard library for embedded targets.  This file comes from the GNU Arm Embedded toolchain.

Comment: @abc Ah. Then it is indeed allowed, and in fact necessary to use a reserved identifier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1` is true, so you can use the macro in an `#if` test. That's not usually very useful for header guards, but it certainly doesn't hurt. For other macros which might be tested in boolean expressions, the true value is definitely useful.

Some people just like the consistency. And that's the definition that `gcc` chooses by default if you put `-D TESTME` on the command line.

However,

```
#define __NEWLIB_H__ 1
```

is not cool unless it's in an implementation of the standard library, because names starting with two underscores (or an underscore and a capital letter) are reserved for use by the implementation, and should never be used in portable applications.

Comment: Okay, yeah someone in the comments made a similar comment, but in this case it is actually an implementation of the standard library.

Comment: Mind specifying what ```-DTESTME``` means?  I couldn't find it in the ~1000 page gcc documentation or on the internet suprisingly.

Comment: @abc: it means "predefine the macro `TESTME`" (in this case to a default value but it's common to provide an explicit value). Used to pass configuration settings into the compilation. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)

Answer (score 3):

When used purely as an `#include` guard, there is no difference between

```
#ifndef __NEWLIB_H__
#define __NEWLIB_H__
```

and

```
#ifndef __NEWLIB_H__
#define __NEWLIB_H__ 1
```

However, in general, there is a distinction.

### Compiler error

```
#ifndef ABCD
#define ABCD
#endif

int main()
{
#if defined(ABCD) && (ABCD == 1)
   std::cout << "ABCD is 1\n";
#else
   std::cout << "ABCD is not 1\n";
#endif
}
```

#### Outputs the string "ABCD is 1"

```
#ifndef ABCD
#define ABCD 1
#endif

int main()
{
#if defined(ABCD) && (ABCD == 1)
   std::cout << "ABCD is 1\n";
#else
   std::cout << "ABCD is not 1\n";
#endif
}
```

#### Outputs the string "ABCD is not 1"

```
#ifndef ABCD
#define ABCD 10
#endif

int main()
{
#if defined(ABCD) && (ABCD == 1)
   std::cout << "ABCD is 1\n";
#else
   std::cout << "ABCD is not 1\n";
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#define` by itself [will replace the symbol with nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23351853/10957435).

On the other hand, `#define 1`, as you call it, will replace the symbol with `1` everywhere it is found in the file. So, for example, the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define EXAMPLE "hello"

int main()
{
    std::cout << EXAMPLE;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
hello
```

This is because `EXAMPLE` here is replaced with `"hello"`, making the print statement equivalent to:

```
std::cout << "hello";
```

If we change the `#define` statement to this instead:

```
#define EXAMPLE
```

[This will give a compile error](https://onlinegdb.com/r18m_T6r8):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
     std::cout << EXAMPLE;
```

As to why you would ever use this second form of `#define`, it's because there is another processor directive that you can use called [`#ifdef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-ifdef-and-hash-ifndef-directives-c-cpp?view=vs-2019):

```
#include <iostream>

#define EXAMPLE

int main()
{
#ifdef EXAMPLE
    std::cout << "EXAMPLE defined.";
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
EXAMPLE defined.
```

Because `#ifdef` (and its relative `#ifndef`) only require that the symbol be defined, we don't really need to give it a value. It just needs to be there to work.

A common place you see this kind of stuff is with [header guards](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/) (which is probably what you're seeing). You can also see it with [platform identification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/142508/10957435), or even [to determine whether the compiler is using C++ or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3789340/10957435).